# Azure domain controllers shutdown deallocation

Tags: azure, active-directory, hyper-v

If I was to shutdown and deallocate a domain controller in azure thus generating a new vmgenerationid what steps do I need to take to recover it?

Comment: What's your mean about recover it? start it?

Comment: Articles online suggest there are issues after the new I'd is generated, the below is taken from an article...                     There is a bit of a “gotcha” with this VM-GenerationID feature. The normal practice to shut down virtual machines in Azure is to do so from the portal or PowerShell. Doing so will deallocate the virtual machine and reset the VM-GenerationID, which is undesirable. We should always shut down domain controllers using the shutdown command in the guest OS, otherwise:

The AD DS database is reset

The RID pool is discarded

SYSVOL is marked as non-authoritative

Comment: could you please show me this link?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.petri.com/best-practices-domain-controller-vms-azure/amp#ampshare=https://www.petri.com/best-practices-domain-controller-vms-azure

Comment: It's also on the madness site.https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj156090.aspx

Comment: I am checking on the query and would get back to you soon on this. I apologize for the inconvenience and appreciate your time and patience in this matter.

Comment: Do you mean you have sysprep that vm, then you want to recover the VM?

Comment: No just shut it down from the azure portal, not within the OS , therefore generating a new vmgenerationid.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what steps do I need to take to recover it?

Yes, a deallocated VM has the advantage of not incurring charges, but it also resets the VM-GenerationID, which is undesirable for a DC.

As we know, vm-generationid used to enable specific applications running in a vm to detect if something has happened to the VM to affect its "place in time". We **can't** restore vm-generationid to the old one.

To obtain the vm-generationid, we can refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj643357(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Note:
>
> You should shut down and restart a VM that runs the domain controller
>   role in Azure within the guest operating system instead of using the
>   Shut Down option in the Azure Management Portal.

More information about Active Directory domain controller with Azure VM, please refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156090.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Is%20it%20safe%20to%20virtualize%20Windows%20Server%20Active%20Directory%20domain%20controllers?).

By the way, here a feedback about change vm-generationid after shutdown VM with Azure Portal or powershell, please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6060983-ensure-virtual-machine-generationid-does-not-chang).

I have **up vote** that feedback, all of the feedback you share in there will be monitored and reviewed by Microsoft engineering teams.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.